Include &shy; character (or equivalent) in Angular's localize library
Using Angular's localize library (@angular/localize) to handle translations in an application. In my German copy however I have certain words that are too long and need a soft hyphen line break opportunity.
If I include the &shy character in the translation file however, it gets rendered as just that. Is there a way to render the line break character correctly, or else prevent the & character from being rendered in html as &amp?
Example translation file (using json format - can use a different format though if it makes a difference):
{
        "home-heading-text": "Folgendes Wort ist sehr lang: Abschieds&shy;geschenk"
}

<h1 i18n="@@home-heading-text">Following word is very long: farewell gift</h1>


You can use the unicode value and it seems to work as expected. Please reduce the size of the stackblitz preview window to a really small size and it will be noticeable.
{
  "home.welcome": "Hello {$name}! You \u00AD have {$messageCount} messages."
}

Forked Stackblitz
Symfony Translations: Soft hyphens (­) in messages yaml file? - deceze ♦ Comment

Thanks, it was the backslash I was missing.
